# How can I erase elements from a vector given a list of iterator?

Tags: c++, vector, c++14

I have a vector of int, and a map which contains as values some iterators pointing to the vector. I need to remove keys from the map, and the vector element the value points to. My code look briefly like that:

```
using RenderData = int;
using Element = std::string;

struct Ref {
    std::vector<RenderData>::iterator ref;
    std::function<int()> update;
    bool should_remove;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<RenderData> ints{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    std::unordered_map<Element, Ref> elements;

    // Here, I need to remove some elements, and their associated number
}
```

I implemented an `erase_if` function that looked like [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/unordered_map/erase_if).

So my initial code looked like that:

```
erase_if(elements, [&](auto&& element) {
    if (element.second.should_remove) {
        ints.erase(element.second.ref);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

It obviously didn't worked. Erasing element makes other iterator to point on wrong object, and in some case out of bound. So I tried that:

```
std::vector<std::vector<RenderData>::iterator> to_remove;

erase_if(elements, [&](auto&& element) {
    // condition based on the string content
    if (element.second.should_remove) {
        to_remove.emplace_back(element.second.ref);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});

// Sort in descending order
std::sort(to_remove.begin(), to_remove.end(), std::greater<>{});

// stuff

for (auto&& it : to_remove) {
    ints.erase(it); // nothing can go wrong right?
}
```

And again, I ended up erasing the wrong elements sometimes.

Given iterators stored in some map, can I remove from the vector the elements the iterators are pointing to?

---

Update:

It seems in the last snippet I swapped some elements in the vector, making erasing the wrong elements. Now it seem to work but I'm still curious what are the methods we can do to erase elements in a vector from an iterator list.

Comment: Bottom line is -- do not store iterators to internal vector items.  Iterator invalidation may occur if the vector is resized.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have a function that resync the elements from the map to the vector when resizing, so this is not a problem for the moment. Maybe with indices it could be faster or easier to do. Though your advice is true, and not following it lead to the pain I currently live.

Comment: *I have a function that resync the elements from the map to the vector when resizing* -- That function is only good if you can, without fail, identify all the places where invalidation may occur.  I would use indices, and to erase elements [go backwards in the array of indices that are to be removed, from highest index to lowest index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039629/c-remove-element-from-dynamic-struct-array-and-shift-other-elements/48040149#48040149), not forward when processing each item.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie _I would use indices_ -- this is what I feared, I may have some refactoring to do then.

Comment: Short answer: use indices. Long answer, If you give more context like what are these data structures and what operations you want to do with them, there may be a better alternative.

Comment: Is that possible erase happens between vector resize and your resync operation?

Comment: @2power10 I carefully call `resync` just after resizing.

Comment: @balki Well, I my code, `Element` contains a bit more data than the iterator, like a flag that tell if the element should be removed, and instead of a vector of ints, it's a vector of rendering data, which are floats, ints, and other simple data like that. Everything, the whole logic is the implementation detail of one class. It's not that far from the code I posted here, I will nevertheless add that to the quesiton.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong you want to remove elements from the vector variable ints is that correct??

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot *I carefully call resync just after resizing* -- `resize()`, `insert()`, `erase()`, `push_back()`, `emplace_back()`, `std::back_inserter` usage.  Did you cover all of those potential calls (maybe I missed some)?

Comment: @Maddy yes. In my example, I call `ints.erase(...)` But I only need to remove a int when I remove an element from the map that points to that int.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes. I have only one function pushing back into the vector, and the vector is private, and that class has no friend. Anyways, the more I'm looking at the problem the more I see that indices may be the right tool to solve it.

Comment: This is a brittle design, but you should be able to make it work. Initialize an iterator to the final element in the vector, iterate over the items to remove, find the item in the map, and `iter_swap` the iterator in the map and the iterator to the last element. After each swap decrement the iterator to the final element by 1. After you're done with all elements, erase the range *[final_iterator + 1, vector.end)*.

Comment: @S.M. sorry, I forgot to edit this one

Comment: FYI, using indices instead of iterators wont work. They will invalidate rest of of the entries in the map.

Comment: Are use sure, that erasing by sorted in reverse order iterators not works? It is strange because standard say opposite.

Comment: @Orient I finally managed to get it work with the sorted iterators. I did things in between that rearranged elements, so I ended up deleting the wrongs objects. It kinda make this question invalid... I wonder if I should close it or post what I said here as an answer.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot You just can add a comment to the second code snippet which describes that there was wrong assumptions.

Comment: I've seen this kind of thing in some high performance apps like games. What seems to be done is to remove elements by marking them empty instead of actually deleting them. When too many elements are empty, do a garbage collection pass that copies everything to a new location and also updates all the maps pointing to the vector. I've also seen variants where a custom deque is used, objects are in maps by object ID (an index not an iterator), object IDs only ever increase, and when early objects get destroyed, empty deque blocks get deallocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the iterator version. 
Note:

1. Iterators are invalidated only when there is a reallocation.
2. Just replace iterators with index does not change the fact that they are invalid when some values are removed from the vector.
3. Using indexes is still a better approach as they don't get invalidated when more elements are added later.

Approach:
Create a copy of vector with elements that should not be removed

```
using Element = std::string;
using RenderData = int;
struct Ref {
    std::vector<RenderData>::iterator itr;
    bool should_remove;
};

struct Main {
    std::vector<RenderData> ints;
    std::unordered_map<Element, Ref> elements;
    void remove_stuff(){
        std::vector<RenderData> localCopy;        
        localCopy.swap(ints);
        ints.reserve(localCopy.size());        
        for(auto it = elements.begin(); it != elements.end();) {
            Ref& ref = it->second;
            if(ref.should_remove) {
                it = elements.erase(it);
            } else {
                ints.push_back(std::move(*ref.itr));
                ref.itr = ints.end() - 1;                
                it++;
            }
        }            
    }
};
```

Link: https://godbolt.org/g/SouZ5E

Comment: Thanks for that! I also noted that I called the resync function in between some operation. I manage to make it work, but this solution seem more solid than mine.

Comment: I managed to make the sorting + erase in a loop work. However your solution is clearly the best, even if I might end up not using this code, it's the most complete and reach it's goal.

Comment: Iterators into a vector are also invalidated in more cases than just reallocation.  The more general rule is, "if any vector element's address changes as a side effect of an operation, consider all the iterators invalid."  Of course, if you swap two elements, it changes the element addresses of those two elements but does not invalidate other element iterators, so this rule is wider than strictly necessary.  But in the exceptional cases, you usually are doing something specific and know when it's safe.  In general, assume size-changing operations to invalidate all iterators.

Comment: `vector<..>::shrink_to_fit` [does invalidate iterators](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/vector#capacity-10) if `ints.size()!=ints.capacity()`. So at the end of `remove_stuff` all `ref.itr` will be invalid iterators if any element is removed.

Comment: Removing the wrong elements is not your only problem. The removal will also invalidate iterators to elements that you do *not* want to remove. I.e. the elements will be still there, but the iterators will no longer be dereferencable. This is one of the usage scenarios where `list` (or `forward_list`) may make more sense than a vector. Also note that your `erase_if` has quadratic time complexity – the more efficient idiom is `container.erase(remove_if(beg, end, pred), end)`.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A : 
You'd better change std::vector with std::list, the iterator of std::list won't be invalid after erase.

Plan B:

```
std::vector<int> newOne;
copy_if(oldOne.begin(), oldPOne.end(), std::back_inserter(newOne), [](){ //to test not in the map ~~ });
oldOne = std::move(newOne)
```

Comment: `std::list` is waaaaay too slow for that. Plan B might work for someone, but I would personally avoid it because of the complexity and the additional allocation needed.

Comment: I guess u wanna a fast remove. U said std::list is too slow, maybe that's not right. U can call 'splice' API of std::list, this will not cause element copy and iterator won't be invalid. Try 'void splice (const_iterator position, list& x, const_iterator i);', add the ones which should be removed to a new list. and delete this list~~

Comment: well, it's true that with a lot of data `std::list` is faster when adding / removing elements, but when it comes from iterating on it, it completely destroys the cache :(

Comment: u may give more context. If u insist on using vector, it's OK, ur solution is meaningful. But I will using 'std::set<iterator, std::great<iterator>>'(descending order) instead of sort. and then foreach to remove iterator-pointed element. This solution is based on the realization of std::vector. But r u make sure this is right for all of the platform ?

Answer (score 1):

Use indices instead of iterators. Replace

```
struct Ref {
    std::vector<RenderData>::iterator ref;
    std::function<int()> update;
    bool should_remove;
};
std::vector< std::vector<RenderData>::iterator> to_remove;
```

with

```
struct Ref {
    std::size_t ref;
    std::function<int()> update;
    bool should_remove;
};
std::vector< std::size_t> to_remove;
```

And then your good idea with descendant sort will be working. To erase an element by index call `ints.erase(ints.begin() + ref)`

Sorting of iterators is a wrong idea. How vector iterators are implemented is not predictable. It is a very small probability that their sort order is the same as for pointers/addresses/indices.

> iterator erase( iterator pos ); (until C++11)
>
> iterator erase( const_iterator pos ); (since C++11)
>
> Removes the element at pos.
>
> Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator.

Comment: I think you should be able to rely on sorting the iterators, as std::random_access_iterator_tag "Can be compared with inequality relational operators (<, >, <= and >=).". I'm not saying it is a good idea, though.

Comment: Neither iterators nor indices work unless you update the remaining references (iterator or index) in the map. E.g. if you have three items stored in the vector at [0], [1], and [2] and you remove item [1] you have to change any references to [2] in the map from [2] to [1]...

Comment: @CAF If you erase elements starting from end to begin iterators keep valid. Iterator Validity (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/): Iterators, pointers and references pointing to position (or first) and beyond are invalidated, with all iterators, pointers and references to elements before position (or first) are guaranteed to keep referring to the same elements they were referring to before the call."

Comment: @S.M. erasing items in sorted order from the back does not solve the problem, that all references to remaining items behind the one with the lowest index need an update...